# XSLT 1.0 - Limit number of records per file

Tags: xml, xslt, visual-studio-2013

I am using an XSLT transformation to generate an XML document which will be split after it is created to produce multiple files. The general structure of the final document is like so:

```
<DOC>
    <NEWFILE/>
    <REALROOT>
        <SENDER></SENDER>
        <INVOICE>
            <IVC_ID></IVS_ID>
            <LINEITEM></LINEITEM>
            <LINEITEM></LINEITEM>
            ...
        </INVOICE>
        <INVOICE>
            <IVC_ID></IVS_ID>
            <LINEITEM></LINEITEM>
            <LINEITEM></LINEITEM>
            ...
        </INVOICE>
        ...
    </REALROOT>

    <NEWFILE/>

    <REALROOT>
        <SENDER></SENDER>
        <INVOICE>
            <IVC_ID></IVS_ID>
            <LINEITEM></LINEITEM>
            <LINEITEM></LINEITEM>
            ...
        </INVOICE>
        <INVOICE>
            <IVC_ID></IVS_ID>
            <LINEITEM></LINEITEM>
            <LINEITEM></LINEITEM>
            ...
        </INVOICE>
        ...
    </REALROOT>
    <NEWFILE/>
</DOC>
```

The `DOC` and `<NEWFILE/>` tags are the boundaries of the end product, but that is not the subject of the question.

My input data needs to be grouped by both sender and invoice before being output to the above structure and I have managed to do that, but I would also like to limit the number of invoices per file and have not been able to find a way to do that.

My input data is broken down into the line item level like so:

```
<ROOT>
    <DATA>
        <SNDR>1</SNDR>
        <INVOICE>1</INVOICE>
        <LINEITEM>1</LINEITEM>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
        <SNDR>1</SNDR>
        <INVOICE>1</INVOICE>
        <LINEITEM>2</LINEITEM>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
        <SNDR>1</SNDR>
        <INVOICE>2</INVOICE>
        <LINEITEM>1</LINEITEM>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
        <SNDR>1</SNDR>
        <INVOICE>3</INVOICE>
        <LINEITEM>1</LINEITEM>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
        <SNDR>1</SNDR>
        <INVOICE>3</INVOICE>
        <LINEITEM>2</LINEITEM>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
        <SNDR>2</SNDR>
        <INVOICE>1</INVOICE>
        <LINEITEM>1</LINEITEM>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
        <SNDR>2</SNDR>
        <INVOICE>2</INVOICE>
        <LINEITEM>1</LINEITEM>
    </DATA>
</ROOT>
```

If I limit it to 2 invoices per file, I would expect this output:

```
<DOC>
    <REALROOT>
        <SENDER>1</SENDER>
        <INVOICE>
            <IVC_ID>1</IVS_ID>
            <LINEITEM>1</LINEITEM>
            <LINEITEM>2</LINEITEM>
        </INVOICE>
        <INVOICE>
            <IVC_ID>2</IVS_ID>
            <LINEITEM>1</LINEITEM>
        </INVOICE>
    </REALROOT>

    <NEWFILE/>

    <REALROOT>
        <SENDER>1</SENDER>
        <INVOICE>
            <IVC_ID>3</IVS_ID>
            <LINEITEM>1</LINEITEM>
            <LINEITEM>2</LINEITEM>
        </INVOICE>
    </REALROOT>

    <NEWFILE/>

    <REALROOT>
        <SENDER>2</SENDER>
        <INVOICE>
            <IVC_ID>1</IVS_ID>
            <LINEITEM>1</LINEITEM>
        </INVOICE>
        <INVOICE>
            <IVC_ID>2</IVS_ID>
            <LINEITEM>1</LINEITEM>
        </INVOICE>
    </REALROOT>
</DOC>
```

Here is what I have to far. This allows me to group the lines by sender and invoice, but I can't figure out how to work in the limit on number of invoices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="data-by-SNDR" match="/ROOT/DATA" use="SNDR"/>
<xsl:key name="data-by-invoice" match="/ROOT/DATA" use="concat(SNDR, INVOICE)"/>

<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <DOC>
        <newFile/>
        <xsl:for-each select="DATA[not(SNDR = preceding-sibling::DATA[1]/SNDR)]">
            <REALROOT>
                <SNDR>
                    <xsl:value-of select="SNDR"/>
                </SNDR>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('data-by-SNDR', current()/SNDR)[not(INVOICE = preceding-sibling::DATA[1]/INVOICE)]">
                    <INVOICE>
                        <IVC_ID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="INVOICE"/>
                        </IVC_ID>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('data-by-invoice',concat(current()/SNDR, current()/INVOICE))">
                            <LINEITEM>
                                <xsl:value-of select="LINEITEM"/>
                            </LINEITEM>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </INVOICE>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </REALROOT>
            <newFile/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </DOC>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You cannot group something that does not exist yet. You need to do this in two passes: first group items into invoices, then group invoices into files.

Comment: XSLT is Turing-complete. If you can produce an output with a programming language, you can produce it with XSLT. Whether it is sane to attempt to is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

First, for each sender, you need a list of all invoices for this sender.

That's already what you're doing with your first two foreach, but I said you need a list. So the second one, needs to not be a foreach. Put these in a variable instead:

```
<xsl:variable name="invoicesWithThisSender"
                    select="key('data-by-SNDR', current()/SNDR)[not(INVOICE = preceding-sibling::DATA[1]/INVOICE)]" />
```

It's the same select, in a variable instead of for-each.

Now you need to write all the elements of this list in as many files it takes.

As XSLT 1.0 does not offer partition mechanisms, the only way I know to do that, is by calling a recursive named template.

Try this:

```
<xsl:template name="writeFilesForSender">
    <xsl:param name="invoicesWithThisSender" />

    <xsl:if test="$invoicesWithThisSender">
        <NEWFILE />

        <REALROOT>
            <SNDR>
                <xsl:value-of select="SNDR" />
            </SNDR>
            <xsl:for-each select="$invoicesWithThisSender[position() &lt;= 2]">
                <INVOICE>
                    <IVC_ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="INVOICE" />
                    </IVC_ID>
                </INVOICE>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </REALROOT>

        <xsl:call-template name="writeFilesForSender">
            <xsl:with-param name="invoicesWithThisSender"
                select="$invoicesWithThisSender[position() > 2]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

call it with this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="writeFilesForSender">
    <xsl:with-param name="invoicesWithThisSender"
        select="$invoicesWithThisSender" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

From what I understand and my tests, your problem is solved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968516/simple-xsl-issue-with-if-statement-inside-for-each/45968983#45968983

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yep, much better. I think it's worth its own answer.