# XSLT for extracting element from all the nodes into groups of 1000 values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML where I need to extract specific element from all the nodes into a group of 1000. The structure of actual XML looks like this-

```
<host> 
<node> 
  <type>fruit1</type>
  <value>1</value>
</node>
<node>
  <type>fruit2</type>
  <value>2</value>
</node>
<node>
  <type>fruit3</type>
  <value>3</value>
</node>
<node>
  <type>fruit4</type>
  <value>4</value>
</node>  
....
....
....
<node>
  <type>fruit1500</type>
  <value>1500</value>
</node>
</host>
```

I have to choose the element  from all the nodes and extract into the format `'fruit1','fruit2','fruit3',...,'fruit1499','fruit1500'` and pass the data into a SQL query `select * from tablename where ColumnName_type IN('fruit1','fruit2','fruit3',...,'fruit1499','fruit1500')`. The issue is I am unable to pass more than 1000 values into SQL IN condition.

Now I have to group first 1000 values into one group and the subsequent 1000 values into an another group and pass it on to the query. The expected sql query is as follows -

```
select * from tablename where ColumnName_type in 
('fruit1','fruit2','fruit3',...,'fruit1000') union all 
select * from tablename where ColumnName_type in 
('fruit1001','fruit1002',...'fruit1500')
```

The XSLT written to extract all the values is as follows-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> <xsl:output method="text" 
encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <xsl:for-each select="//field/value/listValues/value">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:text>'</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::field/code"/>
      <xsl:text>'</xsl:text><xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
    </td>
  </tr> 
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any suggestion to extract the data into groups would be a great help.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968516/simple-xsl-issue-with-if-statement-inside-for-each/45968983#45968983

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, the sample you have shared is to divide the elements into a set whereas my requirement is to custom format the data, divide it into a group of 1000 values and pass it as an input into an sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create groups or batches with a clever combination of modulo and the following-sibling axis. Below stylesheets expects XML like you showed in your question and outputs plain text (SQL statement):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="no" method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="groupSize" select="1000"/>

  <xsl:template match="host">
    <xsl:for-each select="node[position() mod $groupSize = 1]">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
        <xsl:text> union all&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:variable name="values">
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./type"/>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::node[$groupSize > position()]/type">
          <xsl:text>,'</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('select * from tablename where ColumnName_type in &#xa;(', $values, ')')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result using groupSize = 3:

```
select * from tablename where ColumnName_type in 
('fruit1','fruit2','fruit3') union all
select * from tablename where ColumnName_type in 
('fruit4','fruit1500')
```

Answer (score 0):

Reconsider your approach and scale with the power of a relational database. Use XSLT to transform your XML to a tabular formatted file such as CSV for all listed fruits. Then, import the CSV into your database as a temp table.

Practically every major RDBMS can easily import CSVs with convenient methods:

- Oracle/MySQL with `LOAD DATA FILE...`
- Postgres with `COPY mytable FROM...`
- SQLite with command line `.import csv...`
- MS Access with method `DoCmd.TransferText...`
- SQL Server with `BULK INSERT my table...`
- DB2 with `IMPORT FROM...`

Finally, join temp table (i.e., `INNER JOIN`) to your needed table. This avoids repetitious `IN()` clauses and `UNION ALL`, all for a DRY-er solution.

**XSLT** *(transforms xml to csv)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/host">
      <xsl:text>fruit_name&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="node">
        <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CSV** output

```
fruit_name
fruit1
fruit2
fruit3
fruit4
...
fruit1500
```

**SQL** query *(explicit join of table to fruit temp table)*

```sql
SELECT t.* FROM tablename t
INNER JOIN fruit_temptable f
ON t.ColumnName_type = f.fruit_name
```